# Mac OS. Qt. How to get SSID, BSSID and channel of all available WiFi networks

Tags: objective-c, macos

How to get SSID, BSSID  and channel of all available WiFi networks under Mac OS using Qt C++?

Under Windows I use wlanapi.lib and I get mentioned properties via WlanGetNetworkBssList method. Is there any
thing like this under Mac OS? For example, the list of [CWNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/CoreWLAN/Reference/CWNetwork_reference/translated_content/CWNetwork.html) objects.

I'm trying do it in the following way:

```
#import <CoreWLAN/CWInterface.h>

CWInterface *currentInterface = [CWInterface interfaceWithName:nil];

if (currentInterface == NULL)
    return false;

if([currentInterface power])
{
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSSet *scanResults =  [currentInterface scanForNetworksWithBSSID:nil error:&err];

    if (!err)
    {
        for(CWNetwork *network in scanResults)
        {
            //print SSID
        }
    }
}
```

But the call of "scanForNetworksWithBSSID:nil" occurs error : 
"
 Signal name    : SIGTRAP 
 Signal meaning : Trace / breakpoint trap
"

What does it mean?
Could you please advice in this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, just now I'm trying to get the list by using "CoreWLAN/CWInterface.h"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use QProcess and execute a terminal command:

```
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-I";
QProcess process;
process.start("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport", arguments);
```

This will fire off the airport command with the -I flag to show information about the current  wireless network you are on.

Comment: I must to get list of parameters (SSID, BSSID, channel) and process them in the my program.

Comment: The snippet of code I answered with has the SSID, BSSID, and channel in it. You just need to parse the response from the process.

Comment: This only seems to show information about the wifi you are connected to. Not all available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the properties that u can retrieve

```
CWInterface* wifi = [[CWWiFiClient sharedWiFiClient] interface];
NSArray *networkScan = [[wifi scanForNetworksWithName:nil error:nil] allObjects];
for (CWNetwork *network in networkScan) {
    NSLog ( @"SSID: %@ ,\n \
           BSSID: %@ , \n \
           rssiValue: %ld , \n \
           noiseMeasurement: %ld, \n\
           beaconInterval: %ld , \n \
           countryCode: %@ \n ,\
           ibss: %i ,\n\
           wlanChannel: %@ , \n\
           ", [network ssid],[network bssid],[network rssiValue],[network noiseMeasurement],(long)[network beaconInterval], [network countryCode] , [network ibss], [[network wlanChannel]description]);

}
```